# sklearn spectral clustering on graph produces subgraphs with unconnected nodes

Tags: graph, scikit-learn, networkx

I have a networkx graph that I need to cluster. Currently, I am using sklearn and spectral clustering. However, the following code produces subgraphs (clusters) that are not connected, i.e., one cluster can include nodes that are not connected to nodes in the same cluster. The code is as follows.

```
import networkx as nx  
from sklearn.cluster import SpectralClustering

G=nx.Graph()
G=nx.read_edgelist("edges.txt") # graph.txt contains the nodeedge list of your graph

adj_matrix = nx.to_numpy_matrix(G) 
   
clusters = SpectralClustering(affinity = 'precomputed',
                                  assign_labels="kmeans",
                                  random_state= 0,
                                  n_clusters= 4,
                                  n_init=100).fit_predict(adj_matrix)
```

Is there any way I can fix this? If this is better done with another clustering method, I would be interested to know.

Comment: are such nodes connected to _anything_?

Comment: No, they are not connected at all. Initially, all nodes of the initial graph G are connected, but the same isn't true for all clusters.